# Does Responding Quickly to Rebuttal Questions in Peer Review Benefit the Review Process?

Tags: peer-review, academic-life, communication, professionalism

I'm currently in the midst of the peer review process for a paper I've submitted. Recently, I received a set of rebuttal questions from the reviewers. I am able to provide answers to these questions relatively quickly, but I'm unsure if a rapid response is seen as beneficial in the academic community.

Is there a general consensus on whether responding quickly to rebuttal questions during peer review is advantageous? Does it facilitate a more productive conversation or contribute positively to the review process? Or, is the timing of the response generally considered inconsequential as long as the deadlines are met?